# Etymology of "Je... desto.."

Tags: etymology, conjunction, history

German learner (B1) here, and sorry if this sounds like  a stupid question. I've heard about the "Je... desto..." conjunction and I'm familiar with it, but it just sounds *different* than the other conjunctions. To me, it doesn't even *sound* like German.

Did this conjugation come from another place, which would explain how it sounds different? I'm simply asking for the etymology, if it's known.

Answer (score 2):

*Je* is from Old High German *êo* which is loaned from Latin *aeōn*.

*Desto* is a shortening of Old High German *thes thiu* which means *thus*.

Comment: DWDS mentions that "desto" imitates Latin, even though it roots are actually Germanic. Also, DWDS doesn't mention Latin in the etymology of "je", but to me "je" sounds just as German as anything else. A similar phrase is "je ... umso:, but that's not really a mystery; "umso" is just a compound of "um" and "so".

Comment: "je" isn't loaned from Latin *aeōn* (which was borrowed from Greek αἰών)--it's just cognate to it. See [An Etymological Dictionary of the German Language](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/An_Etymological_Dictionary_of_the_German_Language/Annotated/J_(full_text))